# Allowed k value for maximum and minimum phonon frequency in a diatomic lattice

Tags: solid-state-physics, phonons

I've got an expression for the phonon frequency in a diatomic lattice where the atoms are of mass $m$ and $5m$. The expression is $\omega^2=(12Cm\pm\sqrt{(144C^2m^2-20m^2C^2(1-\cos(ka)})))/(10m^2)$. I want to find the maximum and minimum frequency which to me seems to be when $\cos(ka)=1$ so $ka=0,2\pi...$ but I'm not sure if that's physically allowed or not? It doesn't make sense to me for either $a$ or $k$ to be zero. Would I instead need to make a series approximation for when $ka\ll1$ or is my previous statement allowed?
Any help is appreciated

Comment: Why can’t $k$ be zero?

Comment: Wouldn't $k=0$ imply that the wavelength is infinite?

Comment: Well, it is time to wrap your head around $k = 0$ being allowed for crystal wave vectors...

Comment: If you're dealing with an infinite lattice, then infinite wavelength isn't really a problem. I don't think a series expansion would help anything. By definition, the full expression and the expansion would do the same thing in that limit. Have you tried just factoring the $mC$ out of the numerator and plotting $\omega$? That would make the maximum and minimum frequency very clear.